# Julia Array Concatenation dimension mismatch

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, julia

I have a dimensional mismatch problem when using `y =[x,a]` to concatenate my two arrays:

```
x = reshape(1:16, 4, 4)
x = mean((x ./ mean(x,1)),2)'

a = zeros(3)

println(x)

y =[x,a]

print (y)
```

If I try combining them I will get this error:

```
mismatch in dimension 2
```

Both variables x and a appear to be in the same dimensions in the console:

```
println(x)

[0.7307313376278893 0.9102437792092966 1.0897562207907034 1.2692686623721108]

println(a)

[0.0,0.0,0.0]
```

But `x` is in the second dimension. Is there a way to combine the arrays so I can get in dimension 1?

```
y = [0.7307313376278893 0.9102437792092966 1.0897562207907034 1.2692686623721108, 0.0,0.0,0.0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that by transposing x (putting a `'` at the end of the line) you end up with the following:

```
julia> size(x)
(1,4)

julia> size(a)
(3,)
```

So when you try `y=[x,a]` Julia rightfully complains that it cannot concatenate them.

There are (at least) two solutions:

1) Don't transpose x:

```
x = reshape(1:16, 4, 4)
x = mean((x ./ mean(x,1)),2)

a = zeros(3)

println(x)

y =[x,a]

print (y)
```

2) also transpose `a` and concatenate without a comma:

```
x = reshape(1:16, 4, 4)
x = mean((x ./ mean(x,1)),2)'

a = zeros(3)'

println(x)

y =[x a]

print (y)
```

In the first case  you will have `size(y) = (7, 1)` and in the second case you will have `size(y) = (1,7)`, so which option you choose will depend on what you want for the size of `y`.

Comment: I am guessing the display has problems because it is either straight across without commas or straight down without commas in between. Is there a way to change it to a 1xn array like method 2 but with the commas or are the commas just an cosmetic issue?

Comment: Across with commmas = a vector, an inherently one dimensional object. Across without commas = a matrix, with 1 row. The commas are only used for vectors.